# Shutil.move python script not executing or moving files

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I've been trying to write a python script to move .jpg's from one file to another and although the program itself (seemingly) runs to completion as it prints "Task completed", the files do not actually move from one folder to the other. This is the script:

```
    import shutil
    from os.path import join
    import os

    source = join('C','Users','Francisco','Desktop','Test')
    destination1 = join('C','Users','Francisco','Desktop','Archive1')

    for files in source:
        if files.endswith(".JPG"):
            shutil.move(source,destination1)

    print("Task completed");
```

I've tried running the script through both Command Prompt and the IDLE editor module, and even have Python 3.x set as a path in my Environment Variables, but nothing seems to work. I've become very frustrated by being unable to move the images from one folder to another and would like to see if you guy could help me figure out what the issue is here, be it a problem with the script itself or with the python software on my computer.

I'm a beginner at scripting with python so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try printing some stuff out? `for files in source:` isn't doing what you think it is. Put a `print(files)` inside that loop to see what it's actually doing.

Comment: You forgot the colon after the `C` drive letter...

Comment: Once you add the colon and understand the flaw in the loop, search for `glob.glob` to figure out how to get the filenames you want.

Comment: @smarx i did try printing it and youre right it printed the path instead of the files within the folder, how should i fix this?

Comment: (And do make sure to add the missing colon too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through your `source` path characters, not through the actual folder, a quick fix:

```
import os
import shutil

source = os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', 'Francisco', 'Desktop', 'Test')
destination1 = os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', 'Francisco', 'Desktop', 'Archive1')

for filename in os.listdir(source):
    if filename.lower().endswith(".jpg"):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, filename), destination1)

print("Task completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some bugs in your code:

```
import shutil
from os.path import join
import os

source_dir = join('C:/','Users','Francisco','Desktop','Test')
dest = join('C:/','Users','Francisco','Desktop','Archive1')
files = os.listdir(source_dir)

for source in files:
    if source.endswith(".JPG"):
        shutil.move(source, dest)

print("Task completed");
```